# Why does bitbucket display UTF8 characters as junk values while creating PR?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, utf-8, bitbucket, special-characters

I am testing different languages in my project. I use IntelliJ for development and I have set both Global encoding and project encoding to UTF8 in IntelliJ settings. All the language files look normal in IntelliJ, but when I am trying to create a PR in bitbucket, the character are displayed as below image. How to avoid this? Thanks

```
PANE_TITLE_22 = Globale W�hrungstransaktionen
CONT_TITLE_51 = �berf�llige Anzahl
PANE_TITLE_22 = Globale W\uFFFDhrungstransaktionen
CONT_TITLE_51 = \uFFFDberf\uFFFDllige Anzahl
```

```
PANE_TITLE_13 = 帳戶設定檔
PANE_TITLE_15 = 交易管理
PANE_TITLE_22 = 全球貨幣交易
CONT_TITLE_51 = 逾期計數
CONT_TITLE_55 = 有效發卡行
PANE_TITLE_ORIGINAL_58 = 有效帳戶
CONT_TITLE_177 = 有效公司
CONT_TITLE_59 = 鎖定用戶
CONT_TITLE_63 = 老舊交易
CONT_TITLE_67 = 信用額度使用 KPI
CONT_TITLE_157 = 信用額度使用計數
CONT_TITLE_66 = 目前餘額
PANE_TITLE_13 = \u5E33\u6236\u8A2D\u5B9A\u6A94
PANE_TITLE_15 = \u4EA4\u6613\u7BA1\u7406
PANE_TITLE_22 = \u5168\u7403\u8CA8\u5E63\u4EA4\u6613
CONT_TITLE_51 = \u903E\u671F\u8A08\u6578
CONT_TITLE_55 = \u6709\u6548\u767C\u5361\u884C
PANE_TITLE_ORIGINAL_58 = \u6709\u6548\u5E33\u6236
CONT_TITLE_177 = \u6709\u6548\u516C\u53F8
CONT_TITLE_59 = \u9396\u5B9A\u7528\u6236
CONT_TITLE_63 = \u8001\u820A\u4EA4\u6613
CONT_TITLE_67 = \u4FE1\u7528\u984D\u5EA6\u4F7F\u7528 KPI
CONT_TITLE_157 = \u4FE1\u7528\u984D\u5EA6\u4F7F\u7528\u8A08\u6578
CONT_TITLE_66 = \u76EE\u524D\u9918\u984D
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's related to this: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Text-garbled-in-source-code-comment-from-PullRequest/qaq-p/1753890